# Dynamic numbering column in custom Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, custom-list, calculated-column

In SP2010 list I want to have a auto incrementing number column which will also get adjusted when an item from the list gets deleted.

I found a solution from Ali Jafer from following link where he suggests following code:

[Way to keep ID dynamic regarding the number of elements](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177605/way-to-keep-id-dynamic-regarding-the-number-of-elements)

```
/// <summary>
/// An item was deleted.
/// </summary>
public override void ItemDeleted(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    //start the ID count at 1
    int i = 1;
    int paletteInt = 1;
    //need to loop through each item in the whole custom list
    foreach (SPListItem itm in SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["MyCustomList"].Items)
    {
        //as we are going through each item the ID should match our custom ID column. If not update with the correct ID
        if ((int)itm["myID"] != i)
        {
            //update your custom column ID with the new matched ID
            itm["myID"] = i;

           //check every third number of i int, if it is then update the paletteInt number by one 
            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                paletteInt++;
            }

            //update the item after the above has run
            itm["palette"] = paletteInt;
        }
        //increment the ID on each loop
        i++;
    }
    base.ItemDeleted(properties);
}
```

This code looks to perfectly fit my needs but I unfortunately do not know how to add it to my custom list. I unfortunately cannot comment directly to the mentioned thread because of missing reputation.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This code should be added to an `Event Receiver` that will be fired (executed) **after** an `item is being deleted` from your list.

---

**To create an `Event Receiver`, you will need to use `Visual Studio` as the following:**

- Open your Visual Studio.
- Create a new project from File > New > New Project.
- Select `SharePoint 2010 - Empty Project`.

[image]

- Right click on your Project > Add > Add new item > you should now get `Event Receiver` as shown below

[image]

- Follow the `SharePoint Customization wizard`,
- At `What Item Should be the event source.` > select `Custom list`.
- Then select `an item is being deleted`.

[image]

- Click finish.
- Add now your code to the `ItemDeleted` event.
- Build and Deploy.

---

> **Note: To apply an Event Receiver to a specific custom list**
>
> - open `Element.xml` at solution explorer.
> - Change  `<Receivers ListTemplateId="100" >` To  `<Receivers ListUrl="Lists/yourlist">`